# What are the differences between the chain view decorators in SmartPy?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, on-chain-views, off-chain-views

Considering the following SmartPy decorators:

- `@sp.utils.view`
- `@sp.onchain_view`
- `@sp.offchain_view`

What are the differences in use between them?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://gitlab.com/SmartPy/smartpy/-/blob/master/packages/doc/docs/general/views.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `@sp.utils.view`: An old helper that simplifies the creation of an entrypoint that callback a contract with a value. Do not use it except if you know what you are doing.
- `@sp.onchain_view`: an on-chain view is a piece of code that can be called by contracts and also off-chain tools. It is read-only and returns a result.
- `@sp.offchain_view`: isn't uploaded anywhere on the chain. Its code is added to the metadata JSON file/tab generated by SmartPy and must uploaded somewhere and then linked in the metadata bigmap. It can be linked into the metadata. It can be executed by off-chain tools only and is read-only. It returns a result.